# Use the selected file in the rest of the script

Tags: python, function, variables, path, filenames

I am new to Python and therefore have a rather trivial question. I want to select a file in the explorer and then use this file in the script. (See Script or Pic)

```
def browseFiles():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",
                                      title = "Select a File",
                                      filetypes = (("JPG Files",
                                                    "*.jpg*"),
                                                   ("All Files",
                                                    "*.*")))

    label_file_explorer.configure(text="File Opened: "+filename) 

img = Image.open(filename)
```

[filename not defined?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o65Du.jpg)

With def browseFile(): I define manually which file must be selected. This is then "stored" under the variable filename.

If I then want to work in the next lines with the file, or want to nominate it does not recognize me the variable filename.

Therefore the question: How can the file selected above also use below at img = Image.open (filename)?
Do you have examples how I can do this? Thanks

Edit:
See Screenshot - this line is no longer recognized:

```
label_file_explorer.configure(text="File Opened: "+filename)
```

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mVLH.jpg)

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0Lsv.jpg)

This specifies that when a file is selected it will be displayed in the bar along with the path.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the variable `filename` at the end of your function and then call the function to get the `filename` variable:

```
def browseFiles():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",
        title = "Select a File",
        filetypes = (("JPG Files", "*.jpg*"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    return filename

filename = browseFiles()
```

Comment: First of all thank you so far, this works great, just as I imagined, only unfortunately it no longer recognizes me the line: label_file_explorer.configure(text="File Opened: "+filename).
Before changing with the "return filename" the error didn't come, now it says it's not defined....

Comment: Apologis only saw your reply now. How you fixed the issue but if not could you post a new question as this is another type of issue than the one discussed on your question and people familiar with the filedialog object will be able to answer. Good luck!